# Nginx return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; Too Many Redirects

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, https, gunicorn

My Ubuntu 20.10 server has Nginx + Gunicorn + Django Installed. An SSL Certificate has been installed and passes several online SSL/TLS testing assessments. It still displays as unlocked in browsers. Whynopadlock indicated that forcing HTTPS was required. The command  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; breaks the site - infinite redirects.

Might anyone offer suggestions? The sites-available configuration is posted below. Dozens of variations on the following have been tried but to no avail:

```
    #Have tried with and without this:
    upstream django {
    
            server 127.0.0.1:8000;
            keepalive 32;
    }
    
    #Have tried with and without this
    #server {
    #        listen 80 default_server;
    #        server_name www.example.com;
    #        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; #This line breaks site if 1 or 2 server blocks are used
    #}
    
    server {
        listen 80; #Removed this for above server block
        listen 443 ssl;
    
        server_name www.example.com; #Removed www.*
    
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/example/staticfiles/;
        }
    
        location / {
            #Tried many combinations of these:
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;  #Have tried $http and $http_host
             proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_redirect off;
    
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock; #Have tried variations on this with and without trailing'/'
                # and with http and https
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For my project, I use the following:

```
upstream django_server {
    server 172.27.0.1:8000;
}

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS.
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location / {
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - may try some adjustments based on your file and may install LetsEncrypt certificates.